# ReactJS: Disabled field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with a field that allows to choose from a list.

```
     <Column col={'12'} p={'x-0'}>
        {
          this.props.fields.map( (detailLine, index) => {
            return(
              <Column key={`GoodsServicesDataLines_${index}`} id={`GoodsServicesDataLines_${index}`} className="fieldGroup" col="12">
                <Row m={['l-0','r-0']}>
                  <button type={'button'} className={'w-100 close sub-form-delete-button'} onClick={ () => this.removeLine(index) } />

                    <Column col={["lg-9", "md-8"]}>
                      {
                            utility.field({
                              component: Fields.Select,
                              name: `${detailLine}.code`,
                              label: utility.t("PRODUCT", 'product'),
                              col: ["lg-9", "md-8"],
                              data: this.props.ProductsList || [],
                              disabled: true,
                           }
     </Column>
)
```

My problem is that I should disable the field when `data` field is `this.props.ProductsList` while if the data is equal to [] the field shouldn't be disabled. How can i do this in your opinion??

Thank you.

EDIT:

If I tried something like this:

`disabled: this.props.ProductsList`

The field is disable, but if I add another field with a plus button also the new field is disable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
disabled: this.props.ProductsList.length === 0,
```

Comment: I have tried this but the field doesn't become disabled

Comment: And what if you set `disabled: false` ? Is the field disabled ?

Comment: No if it is equal to false. Only if it is equal to true

Comment: I mean true, sorry :') So if the field is properly disable on `disabled:true` it is something on the condition. Can you output `this.props.ProductsList` ?

Comment: It a list of products.The problem is that at the beginning the this.props.ProductsList.length is loaded and equal to 2. So if I create a new field the this.props.ProductsList's value is always equal to 2.

Comment: Alrigth so it's ok with `disabled: this.props.ProductsList` for this field, just change the condition for the other field or remove the property.

Comment: I don't know how to change the condition to other field :(

Comment: I don't know the condition for you :(

Answer (score 0):

You can change `disabled:true` to

```
disabled: !this.props.ProductsList.length
```

Comment: Inverse condition ;)

Comment: I have tried this but the field is not disable. My problem is that if I create another field with a click on a plus button, this new field is disable

Comment: @Jack23, it should work , can you create a working demo on stackblitz?

Comment: It works without "!". 

The problem is that at the beginning the `this.props.ProductsList` is loaded and equal to 2. So if I create a new field the this.props.ProductsList's value is always equal to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hooks - useState for your form fields and onChange method when something is entered in them.

```
const [data,setData]=useState([])
```

---

Update:

You can also try:

disabled: this.props.ProductsList.length > 0 ? false:true

Comment: Sorry I don't have understand what you mean :(

Comment: The problem is the this.props.ProductsList.length is always > 0